# Counting Python pandas Dataframe columns and sorting them by date

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame that looks like;

```
                            ID        Tags       Priority 
Created At
2017-01-01 14:40:00        1234      some_tag     P1
2017-01-02 15:00:00        1345      more_tag     P4
```

I want to count all of the different priority tags for each week to look like;

```
Week       Priority     Count
1            p1           1
             p4           1
```

I've tried the fairly simplet things like:

```
print(df.groupby(df.index.date).count())
```

But that is not giving me what I need.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why did you put `df.index.date` inside of your groupby?

Comment: To count the values by the date in the index

Comment: You also don't possibly expect code to magically figure out that you want to turn your dates into some sort of week grouping do you? Week what? Week of the year? Rolling 7 day week starting with the first of the year?

Comment: Of course not...hence the question

Answer (score 1):

DateTimeIndex has a property called `weekofyear` which suits your needs. Furthermore, you do not only want to group on week, but also on priority. Luckily, the `groupby` function supports taking several attributes to group by:

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd

a = datetime.datetime.now()
b = datetime.datetime.now()
df = pd.DataFrame({'Created At': [a, b], 'ID': [1234, 1235], 'Priority': ['p1', 'p2']}).set_index('Created At')
print(df)

                              ID Priority
Created At                               
2017-02-08 22:25:51.862604  1234       p1
2017-02-08 22:25:57.095862  1235       p2

print(df.groupby([df.index.weekofyear, 'Priority']).count())

            ID
  Priority    
6 p1         1
  p2         1
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `pd.TimeGrouper` with freq `W-Sat` so that `'Sunday'` and `'Monday'` get grouped together.

```
df.groupby([pd.TimeGrouper('W-Mon'), 'Priority']).ID.count().to_frame() 

                     ID
Created At Priority    
2017-01-07 P1         1
           P4         1
```